# Best/Improved way to rescue missing records in Rails 6 when also using pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I'm currently using pundit to authorise my controller methods.

```
after_action :verify_authorized
```

I am also currently use Bugsnag to catch unhandled errors.

I have an application with relatively ephemeral records used by a large audience and often I receive multiple unhandled errors where the record being looked up is no longer present (typically by users unintentionally navigating back to a browser auto-completed URL).

Currently my solution is doing this for each method in my controller:

```
def method_name
  begin
    authorize @record
  rescue
    if @record.nil?
      redirect_to missing_record_path
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You are not authorised to view this record.'
    end
  end

  # rest of code goes here
end
```

There's a lot of code repetition and I'm sure there's a smarter way to handle this whilst also support as an after_action command. What do you think?

Comment: Surely you'll get a missing record error raised before Pundit is even involved?

Comment: Let's have `before_action  :record_finder ` to check for record existence.
e.g 
 `def record_finder  @record = Record.find_by(attr: params[:attr])
return redirect_to missing_record_path unless @record.present? end`